# How to identify last Paragraph of each page in a Word document using Word Interop?

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-interop

I am creating a C# program which makes some automatic changes to several Word documents. One of the requirements is to move the headings to the next page when the following paragraph is in the next page.

The image below exemplify my description:

[image]

At the beginning i did try to identify the headings in the Paragraphs collection (it was possible using info about the style of the headings) because I thought it will be possible to get information about its location in the current page. After some tries, I think that method will not succeed.

I think the key point of this is:

How to identify if a heading is in the last line of a page. However, I do not know if that is feasible.

I will appreciate any suggestion about how to achieve this goal.

Thanks

Comment: That's a Heading not a Header. Try using something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341077/identify-heading-in-an-ms-word-document-using-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for the correction @PredragPetrovic. Regarding the link, Identify the headings is the easy part (I have already done that). The problem is how to know if that heading is at the end of the page

Comment: You don't need code to keep the heading with the paragraph. Use the paragraph setting 'keep we with next' on the heading

Comment: Your are correct @Boeryepes. That was the solution. If you add an answer I will accepted =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need code to keep the heading with the paragraph text. You can achieve this setting the heading paragraph property 'keep with next'.